# Adding created_at DESC functionality in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app with post and comment models. In my index action/view, I am iterating through the post and displaying them from most recently created at to oldest created at. My comments are nested inside my posts so in my post show action/view, I want to iterate though the comments and get them to show from most recently created at to oldest created at. I can only seem to get this to work if i create a method in my `post.rb` file. I have this:

post.rb:

```
  def newest_comments
    self.comments.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

In my post show view, I can iterate through the post comments and it works great:

```
<% @post.newest_comments.each do |comment|
<% end %>
```

BUT I want to set this functionality in the controller layer, but I can't figure out how. This is what I have in the show action in my posts controller:

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

And now my updated post show view:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<% end %>
```

The `@post` var is there because of my before action. So my question is, why do I not have access to this ivar in my post show view by simply calling this in my show view?

Comment: not related about your question but it's not a good practice to use self in class methods.

Comment: Right, this is another reason I want to move this out of my model layer.

Answer (score 20):

With the [updates to Rails](http://railscasts.com/episodes/400-what-s-new-in-rails-4) you can avoid using the `created_at DESC` SQL syntax with something like this:

`@comments = @post.comments.order(created_at: :desc)`

Answer (score 8):

You can use a scope

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :newest_first, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

then you use it like

```
@comments = Comment.newest_first
```

And `@comments` is going to be ordered

Comment: You might need to make the scope body callable (to evaluate the block's content every time the scope is used). To do this, use: `scope: newest_first, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }`

Comment: @joseramonc scope is not callable unless you put the evaluating code in a block, please update the code as  `scope: newest_first, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }.`

Comment: Thanks, just fixed it

Answer (score 3):

Right now your code of show action is like return all comments, instead of comments related to post. To access @post in show view you have to update your show action like this.

```
 def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comment.new
    @comments = @post.comments.order("created_at DESC")
 end
```

So in this way you can access @post and @comments in Show view.

And now update post show view like this to show comments:

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
<% end %
```

Also for You can user @post object in view as well if required.
@comments for new comment.

You can see this Post-Comment app on Rails-guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#showing-posts
Other helpful links : http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/32-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step

Answer (score 1):

you can define ordering in post model:

```
class Post
  has_many :comments, :order => 'created_at DESC'
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I never knew that you could add that at the model layer like that. Do you know how I could also do this at the controller layer? I am still new to Rails, but now I have seen this being done at the model layer through a def method, your way at the model layer and through the controller layer...any best practices?

Comment: you may also want to try has_scope gem for conditional sorting / filtering

Answer (score 1):

use this in your comment model for set default order:

```
default_scope { order("created_at DESC") }
```